# What is the Dunford Integral and why is it useful?

Tags: integration, banach-spaces

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral) defines the Pettis Integral for Banach space valued functions on a measure space by duality. Apparently there is a Dunford integral which specializes to the Pettis integral. What is its definition, why are these integrals useful, and how are they related to the [Bochner Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)?